# Why does object exported in ES6 module have undefined methods?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have an ES6 class defined in an ES6 module that exports an *instance* of that class:

```
class MyObject {
  constructor() {
    this.propertyA = 1;
    this.propertyB = 2;
  }

  myMethod() {
    doStuff();
  }
}

var theInstance = new MyObject();
export default theInstance;
```

When I import this module, `myMethod` is `undefined`:

```
import * as theObject from './my/module';

theObject.myMethod(); // Error! undefined is not a method.
```

The properties defined in the constructor *do* exist. It's as though the object's *prototype* was excluded, and only its *members* were exported.

I am requiring `'babel/register'`.

Why is exporting this object not working correctly?

Comment: Strangely enough, exporting an instance of `new` solved my problem. I had been trying to export the _class definition_, and instantiate `new` in the "importer" file. That gave me the error. But _exporting_ `new`, it worked! Your problem, my solution. **shrug**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured this out right after asking. It looks like there's a difference between `import * as foo from 'module'` and `import foo from 'module'`. This works:

```
import theObject from './mymodule';
```

So it wasn't a matter of the wrong thing being exported, but it was being imported incorrectly.

Comment: Yes. `import x from '...'` imports the **default** export. And that's what you have (`export default new MyObject()`). `import * as x from '...'` imports all **named** exports as properties of an object. You can import a subset via `import {foo, bar} from '...'`. Named export are of the form `export function foo() {}` or `export var bar = ...;` or `export {abc, xyz}`.

Comment: Maybe it's just a `babel` thing, but apparently `import *`, if you had an `export default`, imports immediate properties of the default object. Do you know if that's the official behavior or if that's just part of how babel transpiles?

Comment: Do you mean `import * from 'something'`? That is actually invalid. Here are the valid declarations: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#table-40

Comment: No, I mean `import * as foo from 'something'` like I had originally tried.

Comment: That should not happen, although it might be due to interoperability between ES6 modules and CommonJS modules.

Comment: In my question, it was between two ES6 modules, but both are transpiled via babel, so maybe it's an implementation detail? It's not clear to me in the spec yet if `import *` should get the default export, or if it does, that the prototype of the exported object is omitted.

Comment: No it should not. The default export and named exports are completely independent. Think about the default export as a named export with the predefined name "default". Only in CommonJS are they conflated, and that's what makes it tricky to make ES6 modules work properly on a CommonJS environment.

Comment: I think http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/modules/#interop explains it. Thanks for the clarifications!